# Windows 7 UPnP while turned off, spams event viewer

Tags: windows-7, upnp

I have Win 7 Pro, EventViewer is spammed every 10 minutes with EventID 10016, which is described [here](https://www.eventid.net/display-eventid-10016-source-DCOM-eventno-4718-phase-1.htm). I ask myself (and now everyone reading this) WHY, because I have turned off Windows Media Extender service and PnP-X IP enumerating service? Error description says it can't launch IPBusEnum service, well I say, thats good, I have turned it off!

If someone could explain to me why am I seeing tons of these and what else could depend on IPBusEnum service that could be turned off.

Best Regards